# Adding processing code to a webpage using processing.js

Tags: processing, processing.js

I have created a Processing code (.pde file) to make a time series (coffee production v/s time) which takes its data from an excel file(.tsv table). Can anyone tell me how to include this to my webpage?
I have tried with processing.js but it does not show anything in the browser.

Comment: How did you tried? Why does not work? How is the code? Using any library? Is it working in the IDE? Any error in browser console?

Answer (score 0):

without additional information, you probably have your .tsv file in a "data" directory, but aren't explicitly loading it from "./data/myfile.tsv", instead relying on Processing to autoresolve. If you intend to use your sketch online, always include "data/" in your file locations, because browsers resolve locations relative to "where the page is right now".